How to Retrieve bill-name and bill-address from Amazon SP-API Order Report
I am using Amazon SP-API and trying to retrieve data equivalent to the order report that can be downloaded from Seller Central. The marketplace in question is Japan.
What are the details of your problem?
I tried using the GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_SHIPPING endpoint, which provides similar data, but it lacks the following fields:
- bill-name
- bill-address-1
- bill-address-2
- bill-address-3

I cannot find an endpoint that includes these fields.
I used the GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_SHIPPING endpoint, but it did not include the above fields. Since these fields are available in the order report downloadable from Seller Central, I expected to retrieve similar data through the API.
If anyone knows how to obtain this information, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.
